# Stellar balances

Tags: transactions

I am trying to write a query to find out stellar balances(for all addresses)but I am not able to get the correct operations to consider in that , maybe because I don't understand stellar very well .

So , the questions I have are as follows .

1. How to calculate balance of an address with query. I have a very simple query but not giving correct balances . Here currency_id is for stellar .

```
SELECT 
 
  sum(in_value_xlm) total_in, 
  sum(out_value_xlm) total_out, 
  tx_date,
  total_in - total_out AS balance

  FROM 
  (
SELECT
   0 AS in_value_xlm,
   sum(toFloat64(value_from) / 10000000) AS out_value_xlm,
   tx_date
   
FROM stellar_flow.transfers_from
WHERE (transfer_from = '{{ addr }}') AND (currency_from_id = 417896) 
GROUP BY tx_date
UNION All 
SELECT
   sum(toFloat64(value_to) / 10000000) AS in_value_xlm,
   0 AS out_value_xlm,
   tx_date
FROM stellar_flow.transfers_to
WHERE (transfer_to = '{{ addr }}') AND (currency_to_id = 417896) 
GROUP BY tx_date
)
GROUP BY tx_date
```

2. Is there any website/page where I can find daily address stellar balance of an address , similar to stellar expert .

Thank you

Comment: Where is this data originating from? The schema doesn't look like anything standard, Is this a custom database you are using?

Comment: Hey , Yes this is a custom database .I wanted to know what all operations to keep in mind for calculation for balances of an address

Answer (score 1):

If you have [operation type](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/stellar/go/xdr#OperationType) included in your table, make sure to include the following operations, which impact the account balance:

- 1 - `payment`
- 2 - `path_payment_strict_receive`
- 3 - `manage_sell_offer`, only once the trade executes
- 4 - `manage_buy_offer`, only once the trade executes
- 8 - `account_merge`
- 13 - `path_payment_strict_receive`
- 15 - `claim_claimable_balance`
- 22 - `liquidity_pool_deposit`
- 23 - `liquidity_pool_withdraw`

Stellar Expert is an excellent real time source for account balances; you can use the website or their [Directory API](https://stellar.expert/openapi.html#tag/Directory-API). The [Horizon API](https://developers.stellar.org/api/introduction/) also fetches account balance details in real time.

If you want a daily dump of the data, you could use the publicly available [GCP dataset](https://www.stellar.org/developers-blog/try-our-new-analytics-dataset?locale=en) to query the `accounts` table directly and create an extract.